# MongoDB - use $lte in datetime for hours only

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My data looks like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b62f97e3c2094eefa912aba"),
    "FietsID" : 1267,
    "Stad" : "Antwerpen",
    "Accelerometer" : 1.0,
    "Decibel" : null,
    "Datum" : ISODate("2017-06-06T05:45:06.000Z"),
    "Location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            22.50891, 
            48.54121
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b62f97e3c2094eefa9128cc"),
    "FietsID" : 1971,
    "Stad" : "Antwerpen",
    "Accelerometer" : 1.0,
    "Decibel" : 55,
    "Datum" : ISODate("2017-06-11T18:17:21.000Z"),
    "Location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            -38.23146, 
            -6.75194
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to get all the data where the time is lower than 06:00:00, Decibel higher than 90, and 'Stad' only Antwerpen

I've tried to work with aggregate `$dateToString` but than it seems I only can use 1 parameter for match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) operator available in 3.6 to use aggregation operators in find query and [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) to include all conditions.

Use [`$hour`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) to get hour from date.

Something like

```
db.colname.find
({"$expr":{
  "$and":[
    {"$lte":[{"$hour":"$Datum"},6]},
    {"$gt":["$Decibel",90]},
    {"$gt":["$Stad","Antwerpen"]}
  ]
}})
```

Comment: Already tried working with $expr, but I get the error message:


Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $expr",
 "code" : 2,
 "codeName" : "BadValue"
}

Comment: Yeah you are not on 3.6. Is it possible you to upgrade to 3,6 ?

Comment: Yeah indeed, I thought I was on 3.6 but I just checked. I will update to 3.6 thanks!